# Можно ли задать условие, чтобы передать или не передавать параметр у объекта в JS?

Tags: javascript

Существует простая функция, возвращающий переданный в нее объект. Если `flag === true` то мы передаем весь объект, если false - мы не передаем параметр `age`. Здесь я использую тернарный оператор и просто передаю разные объекты в зависимости от флага.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы тернарник (или нечто другое) исходя из условия определяла: передавать ли параметр или нет ВНУТРИ ОДНОГО объекта?

```
const example = (obj) => obj;
    
const flag = true;

const answer = example(flag ? { name: 'Max', age: 22 } : { name: 'Max' });
```

Comment: Это теоретическая задачка? или есть конкретное применение?

Comment: Это оч упрощенно, но в целом да, если такое возможно, то можно применить в реальном проекте. Просто интересно: это вообще возможно?

Comment: https://qastack.ru/programming/34698905/how-can-i-clone-a-javascript-object-except-for-one-key
Вот тут посмотрите, есть разные варианты от удаления "ключ: значение", до заглушки типа, "ключ: undefined".
Обратите внимание, нужно изменять исходный объект, или все операции проводятся с копией исходного объекта.